# Paypal createSubscription() Error in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, paypal-sandbox

I am using laravel as a backend and vuejs as a front end. I have created plan an product using the paypal end points on the backend. When I put the paypal button inside vue and click it. It throws me this error.

[image]

```
        paypal.Buttons({
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.subscription.create({
        plan_id: "plan-id"
      });
    },

    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      alert(
        "You have successfully created subscription " + data.subscriptionID
      );
    }
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container");
```

Comment: As the error message says, it's an error with the endpoint that's returning a 500 response. Check if you're using the API as intended and if it's actually working: it has nothing to do with your client-side code I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi @Terry. Thank you for your response but paypal itself hits this endpoint when I click the button. I am not hitting this end point as you can see in the above mentioned code.

Comment: It's a third party issue, contact their tech support instead.

Comment: Ok. But I think it's a client configuration error. I am missing something at the client side. As is mentioned in the error 'update_client_config_error'. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Then check their documentation and see what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use direct HTTPS API calls to implement [the Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/).

The PayPal-PHP-SDK 's use of billing plans is old and not compatible with the latest versions of the subscriptions API. You should not use the PayPal-PHP-SDK for anything, it is obsolete at this point (use the Checkout-PHP-SDK for regular, non-Subscription payments, and direct HTTPS API calls for the Subscriptions API).

You can test this with command-line curl or Postman calls first, to make sure it works, and then implement the necessary PHP function to do a direct HTTPS API call with the oauth token

Comment: Hi @Preston PHX, thank you for you response. The issue here is that I am not doing any api calls. I am just using paypal provided button for subscription which when clicked gives this error.